# How to convert a string to an array of dicts

Tags: javascript, json

I want to convert a string in this format:

```
'[{"param":"MDN","required":"true"},{"param":"Attribute","required":"false"}]'
```

to an array of dicts, such that I can easily parse through them.

I have tried using regex and such, but I am not able to figure it out.

```
contents = contents.substring(1, contents.length-1);
var variables = contents.split(",");
```

I tried to remove the first and last character of the string, the square brackets and then split with commas, but the problem is that the dictionaries inside them have commas.

The final result should be:

```
[{"param":"MDN","required":"true"},{"param":"Attribute","required":"false"}]
```

Same as input, but not a string anymore.

Comment: use JSON.parse('[{"param":"MDN","required":"true"},{"param":"Attribute","required":"false"}]')

Comment: Check what `JSON.parse()` can do for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean just [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)?

```js
const parsed = JSON.parse('[{"param":"MDN","required":"true"},{"param":"Attribute","required":"false"}]')

console.dir(parsed)
```

Comment: @user3386236 The biggest breakthroughs in science are generally made when something unknown is understood to be equivalent to something else that is known. "A string of format X" just happens to be JSON ;)